How to invoke devops API in WSO2 API Manager with access token?
I'm trying to use Devops API in WSO2 API Manager 4.3 to control the logging levels. The question is how to use an access token (bearer) instead of Basic Auth(username & password) to invoke this API. Are there specific scopes to be added? Or is this not possible?
DevOps API Guide
